# I need help in python so that it triggers something when a value is high and then low

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

There is one part of my code where it reads the input from an ultrasonic sensor and if the distance is low but then high it triggers an alarm.

Here is my first attempt (sadly it didn't work):

```
if result < '5':
        if result >= '10':
            GPIO.output(14, 1)
```

Comment: can you explain more what you mean by low then high? Nothing executes between your conditional statements. you'll never reach your output because result cannot be both < 5 and >= 10. You also probably want to cast then numbers to integers since I don't think the string comparison will give you what you want

Comment: You are comparing `result` to strings and not numbers. I do not think that this is what you want. Use `5` instead of `'5'` for that. Same for `'10'`. On top of that, can you please clarify your problem. What do you mean by 'low then high'? What's the timeline here?

Comment: Everyone the part of the code is not the ultrasonic sensor it is the part that uses the ultrasonic sensor input. That says that if the value is low and then a few seconds later the value is high sound the alarm

Comment: The result is the distance measurement of the ultrasonic sensor

Comment: Please share some more code or something that shows more information.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, when the value of `result` is at some point below the value `5` and at some time afterwards goes above `10`, you want the GPIO to go high?!

I will briefly sketch an example, how this can be done. In this example you need to store the information that the value has been below `5` in another variable. When `result` has been below `5` at any time, the value of `flag_below` will be `1`.

Inside the while loop you will also have to place the reading of the sensor, which assigns the new value to `result`.

```
flag_below=0
while True:
    if result < 5:
        flag_below=1
    if result >= 10 and flag_below==1:
        GPIO.output(14, 1)
```

Of course this only will set the GPIO high once and leave it there. Depending on your needs you will also have to add code to reset the GPIO.

By the way, as mentioned in the comment by @Learning is a mess you need to compare `result` against a number not a string.

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not expert but also doing the same.
2. You can do it by first measuring the distance and then triggering something according to that as explained below-

## **get distance of the object from sensor**

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
TRIG = 8
ECHO = 10
print("Distance measurement in progress...")
GPIO.setup(TRIG, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
print("waiting for sensor...")
time.sleep(2)
GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
time.sleep(0.00001)
GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:
    pulse_start = time.time()
while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
    pulse_end = time.time()
pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
distance = pulse_duration * 17150
distance = round(distance, 2) #distance is in centimeter here
```

**according to distance of object we can perform any action**

```
if distance < 800:
    print("somthing......")
else:
    print('something else...')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @lemon Thanks for suggesting i hope it's better now to understand.